# apache http DELETE request - how does it work - how long should it take

Tags: apache, http, apache2

**1) Initial question**:
How long should a DELETE request to an apache webserver take.
Is it possible to take over 3 minutes? (judging from apache logs)

**2) Followup question**:
How does a DELETE request "normally" work. Does it just trigger the deletion of a file to the unerlying system (which I guess would just remove the link to the file, which shouldn't take that long) - or does it wait until the file is really deleted.

**1) Background**:
(Files for the apache2 are served from the mount nfs system)
There was a legacy apache2 (2.2.22) on Debian7 with an nfs-mount (1.2.6, mounted with vers=4) which was updated to apache2 (2.4.54) on Debian11 with nfs-mount (1.3.4, mounted with vers=4.2).

After the migration some GET/PUT/DELETE request take over 200seconds or 300seconds which where not seen in month before.
Because for GET and PUT it may also depend on filesize and parallel requests, I'm specifically asking for DELETE requests.
I see those long running DELETE reqeusts with either successful (200) and non-successfull (404) returncode

**2) Background**:
From my understanding, even if a filesize is small or big, the DELETE reqeust shouldnt take that long, but I'm not sure how the DELETE works (despite of what I read in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE )